# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '4303712665A'

Tags: mysql, database

here is the error log

```
[http-nio-8093-exec-6] INFO  com.jfz.pc.interceptor.SqlCostInterceptor  62 - ============>SQL：[UPDATE jfz_simu_vip_net_remind SET prd_code='P7raoxwpmo', is_update_net='1', uid='5314221707', update_time='1706669051', state='1', phone='【i can not show the customer phone, so i hide it】', trigger_mode='2', platform='0' WHERE (uid = '5314221707' AND prd_code = 'P7raoxwpmo'), 执行耗时: 8 ms]==========
[http-nio-8093-exec-6] INFO  com.jfz.pc.aspect.LogPrintAspect  60 - ================= End ==================

[http-nio-8093-exec-6] ERROR com.jfz.pc.advice.ExceptionControllerAdvice  68 - 接口访问异常[/utils/choice/add]
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '4303712665A'
### The error may exist in com/jfz/pc/mapper/result/JfzSimuVipNetRemindMapper.java (best guess)
### The error may involve com.jfz.pc.mapper.result.JfzSimuVipNetRemindMapper.update-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE jfz_simu_vip_net_remind  SET prd_code=?, is_update_net=?,    uid=?, update_time=?, state=?, phone=?,  trigger_mode=?, platform=?      WHERE (uid = ? AND prd_code = ?)
### Cause: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '4303712665A'
; Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '4303712665A'
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:100)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:70)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:79)
        at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:91)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy125.update(Unknown Source)
        at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.update(SqlSessionTemplate.java:288)
        at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperMethod.execute(MybatisMapperMethod.java:64)
        at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:148)
        at com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.override.MybatisMapperProxy.invoke(MybatisMapperProxy.java:89)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy212.update(Unknown Source)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2031.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:49)
```

this is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `jfz_simu_vip_net_remind` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
      `prd_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
      `is_update_net` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL ,
      `is_net_to_price` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL ,
      `net_up` decimal(22,8) DEFAULT NULL ,
      `net_down` decimal(22,8) DEFAULT NULL ,
      `uid` varchar(20) NOT NULL ,
      `update_time` int(11) DEFAULT NULL ,
      `state` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1' ,
      `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL ,
      `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
      `trigger_mode` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '2' ,
      `platform` tinyint(2) DEFAULT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `prd_code` (`prd_code`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `uid` (`uid`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I used mybatis-plus in this project, the releated method code is as follows

```
public boolean addSimuVipNetRemind(Long uid, String prdCode, String phone, int platform) {
    LambdaQueryWrapper<JfzSimuVipNetRemind> wrapper = Wrappers.lambdaQuery(JfzSimuVipNetRemind.class)
            .eq(JfzSimuVipNetRemind::getUid, uid)
            .eq(JfzSimuVipNetRemind::getPrdCode, prdCode)
            .last("limit 1");

    JfzSimuVipNetRemind one = getOne(wrapper);
    if (Objects.isNull(one)) {
        one = new JfzSimuVipNetRemind();
    }
    one.setUid(String.valueOf(uid));
    one.setPrdCode(prdCode);
    one.setUpdateTime((int) (new Date().getTime() / 1000));
    one.setPhone(phone);
    one.setIsUpdateNet(JfzSimuVipNetRemind.IS_UPDATE_NET_TRUE);
    one.setTriggerMode(JfzSimuVipNetRemind.TRIGGER_MODE_MANUALLY);
    one.setState(JfzSimuVipNetRemind.STATE_OK);
    one.setPlatform(platform);

    LambdaQueryWrapper<JfzSimuVipNetRemind> updateWrapper = Wrappers.lambdaQuery(JfzSimuVipNetRemind.class)
            .eq(JfzSimuVipNetRemind::getUid, uid)
            .eq(JfzSimuVipNetRemind::getPrdCode, prdCode);
    return this.saveOrUpdate(one, updateWrapper);
}
```

the sql print by interceptor dose not contain the value '4303712665A', but I check the data find '4303712665' is another uid, i don't know why is print here and where the 'A' comes from, any one have meet this problem?

Comment: Does any trigger exists on this table? PS. 5 columns which are used in your query (`is_update_net, update_time, state='1', trigger_mode, platform`) are of numeric datatype. Why do you provide string-type values for them?

Comment: there is no trigger exists,  in fact I don't provide string-type values, the sql was generated by mybatis-plus and I provide the code above

Comment: Try setting one column at a time to see which one causes the error. Then check the value of the corresponding variable.

Comment: It sounds like the bad string is coming from the _caller_ of `addSimuVipNetRemind()`.  MySQL is not involved.